# How many words give 98% coverage in Mandarin?

Tags: vocabulary, chinese

For Chinese characters, [Jun Da's dataset](https://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=MO) implies 1566 characters gives 95% coverage, 2285 characters gives 98% coverage, and 2838 characters gives 99% coverage.  I'm wondering if there's a similar result for words.

**Question**: How many words give 98% coverage in Mandarin?

It seems substantially more challenging to compute for words, since it's hard to define what a "word" is.  I did some Googling, but didn't immediately find anything concrete.  [This webpage](https://hskhsk.com/2/post/2013/04/how-much-will-i-understand-at-each-hsk-level) says HSK6's 5000 words is enough for between 77.2% and 98.2%, which is so broad to be almost useless (perhaps this reflects the difficulty of this question).

[This LingQ post](https://www.lingq.com/en/forum/open-forum/vocabulary-coverage-ratios/) gives

> 1000 words covers 73.0%
> 2000 words covers 82.2%
> 5000 words covers 91.64%

citing [a Japanese book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%9B%B3%E8%A7%A3-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E-%E6%B2%96%E6%A3%AE-%E5%8D%93%E4%B9%9F/dp/4385362424).  [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/ik83k5/oc_how_far_does_your_chinese_vocabulary_get_you/) says 7000 words gives 95% coverage (derived from the SUBTLEX-CH corpus).  The Redditor [goes on](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/ik83k5/comment/g3ivueo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and states 16,000 words is enough for 98% coverage; it's not clear where this claim comes from.  This is the best approximation I have for now.

[This list](https://github.com/orgtre/google-books-ngram-frequency/blob/main/ngrams/1grams_chinese_simplified.csv) gives 95% coverage for the first 10000 simplified Chinese "1-grams".

Comment: 'since it's hard to define what a "word" is'. It usually is, but since Standard Chinese has no morphology, I think it would be acceptable to use "lexical item" as a definition of "word". The trouble is that this solves only one side of the question, because you still need a good electronic dictionary and a representative corpus to do the actual computational work.